# Como impedir que o usuário cadastre uma data futura usando o método validate laravel-7

Tags: php, laravel, validação

Quero validator uma data para impedir que o usuário cadastre uma data de nascimento futura, por exemplo a data de amanhã.

Comecei a validação do meu formulário da seguinte forma, usando o método validate:

```php
$request->validate([
    'user' => 'required|min:5|max:50|unique:user',
    'senha' => 'required|min:5|max:50',
    'confirmar' => 'required|min:5|max:50',
    'data' => 'required|date',
    'email' => 'email',
]);
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma regra de `before_or_equal` usando o dia de hoje como margem. A [documentação aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-before-or-equal).

```php
$request->validate([
    'user' => 'required|min:5|max:50|unique:user',
    'senha' => 'required|min:5|max:50',
    'confirmar' => 'required|min:5|max:50',
    'data' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:today',
    'email' => 'email',
]);
```